# How to implement both input search and dropdown filter for a json data in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngrx-data

I am trying to implement a search filter and dropdown filter for JSON data. using that data I need to filter my table using separate search filter and dropdown filter. only the search filter I have implemented and works fine but stuck in the dropdown filter.
[URL of images what I have created]
[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpNt5.png]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu32a.png

Comment: For Dropdown filter you first need to take value selected by dropdown, and then pass this selected dropdown value to filter table and then filter on table.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, can you please help me with the code. How we can do that?

Comment: Did you use any component library for table ? or its simple html table element like `<table>` ?@TusharSinare